# How to do image processing using gstreamer like opencv?

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, gstreamer, video-capture

I have one project in which I am doing some object detection using deep learning. I have tried to read video frames using OpenCV,but it was too slow. May be near to 1fps. I have switched on gstreamer but I do not know how I can read frame by frame a video file using it, after reading in that way i want to do object detection as well. How can I do that? any source code is appreciated. I am on windows 10 and Python 3.6 on Anaconda environment.

Comment: 1 fps is way to slow. Can you post a code example of what you're doing?

Comment: I am not sure about 1fps but opencv is slow to display video streams when it comes to HD videos. That is why i need something faster like gstreamer.

Comment: If you want to implement your own object detection with GStreamer, you'd better program your own GStreamer plugin (unless you find one that is appropriate for your purposes by chance)

Comment: why don't you post an example to see if it is really that slow. I've displayed 1080p video from opencv with no problems (with ffmpeg as backend)

Comment: I am just using videocapture and imshow functions from opencv. So can you help me that how can I use ffmpeg as backend?